# Why would it throws "'module' object has no attribute XXX" error when I call on apply_async from multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The code is as below. When I copy-and-paste it in my cmd prompt, it throws **'module' object has no attribute 'func'**, but when I save it as a **.py** file and execute `python test.py`, it just works fine.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(msg):
    for i in xrange(3):
        print msg
        time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in xrange(5):
        msg = "hello %d" %(i)
        pool.apply_async(func, (msg, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "Sub-process(es) done."
```

Could anyone give me an explanation on the difference between in prompt and in file when running a python code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure why unutbu deleted his answer, but he was correct: [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) state pretty clearly up front that `Pool` will not work in an interactive interpreter.

Comment: I deleted it because I felt the OP was asking for why this happens, not just that the docs say that it does happen.

Comment: @unutbu ah, reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because on Windows, `func` needs to be pickled and sent to the child process via IPC. In order for the child to unpickle `func`, it needs to be able to import it from the parent's `__main__` module. When this happens in a normal Python script, the child can re-import your script, and `__main__` will contain all the functions declared at the top-level of your script, so it works fine. However, in the interactive interpreter, functions you've defined while in the interpreter can't simply be re-imported from a file like in a normal script, so they will *not* be in `__main__` in the child. This is more clear if you use `multiprocessing.Process` directly to recreate the issue:

```
>>> def f():
...  print "HI"
...
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f)
>>> p.start()
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

This way, it's more clear that `pickle` can't find the module. If you add some tracing to `pickle.py` you can see that `'module'` is referring to `__main__`:

```
def load_global(self):
    module = self.readline()[:-1]
    name = self.readline()[:-1]
    print("module {} name {}".format(module, name))  # I added this.
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
    self.append(klass)
```

Rrerunning the same code again with that extra print statement yields this:

```
module multiprocessing.process name Process
module __main__ name f
< same traceback as before>
```

It's worth noting that this example actually works fine on Posix platforms, because `os.fork()` is used to spawn the child processes, which means that any function defined prior to the `Pool` being created will be available in the child's `__main__` module. So, while the above example will work, this one will still fail, because the worker function is defined *after* creating the `Pool` (which means after `os.fork()` is called):

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
>>> def f(a):
...  print(a)
... 
>>> p.apply(f, "hi")
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 231, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 57, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 339, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Comment: Any workarounds for this? I'm doing some interpreter execution from a Gimp plugin, the Python-Fu console, and this behavior is a blocker currently.